# Sound effects distorting?

Tags: swift, skaction, soundeffect

I have create a flappy bird like game.

Each time the screen is touched during game a flapping sound is played using

```
 run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("flapSound.caf", waitForCompletion: true))
```

I have noticed that during gameplay this sound will randomly distort for a certain period of time. It also distorts the sound I have when the bird collects coins. It eventually goes back to normal but it seems to always happen! Sometimes the sound won't play at all!

Has anyone ever experienced this type of problem?

Comment: Use an audio file variable, initialing it with the file name.

Comment: Really? I read it was better to use an SKAction when doing short and frequent sound effects?